# assigning const char *ptr to an array parameter? C++

Tags: c++

FYI:  the answer provided was wrong, I have found an answer, they are written below.

In an exam question, was given a function prototype

```
void store(double *ptr, unsigned int length, char filename[]);
```

we are asked to call this function in order to do stuff... (not relevant to my question now).
but we need to pass a filename for reading.  and it must be received by this `filename[]` char array.
below is the answer that is provided.  (it's a previous years' exam).

---

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
#define SIZE 10
int main(void)
{
 const char *filename = "array.dat";
 double a[SIZE];
 for ( unsigned n = 0; n < SIZE; n++ )
 a[n] = 0.0;
 store(a, SIZE, filename);        // if simply send "array.dat" as parameter it works.
 return 0;
}
```

---

however, this does not compile to me.  in my mind it doesn't compile either, because I can't assign a c-style string like this to a char array, in this way, or so i believed.  I've searched a fair bit, i just need some clarity on this. thanks.

Comment: You should provide char array as filename element, not string literal

Comment: `char filename[]` is really `char* filename`. And it cannot be assigned from a `const char*`. That is why the example should not compile.

Comment: Yeah, `const` is the crux here.

Answer (score 3):

The line

```
const char *filename = "array.dat";
```

defines `filename` to be of type `const char*`. It cannot be used as an argument to `store` since `store` expects `char []` type.

Change the declaration of `filename` to:

```
char filename[] = "array.dat";
```

Comment: thanks, however, this is the "right" answer provided.  Unless, could you absolutely say this is a fault on my lecturers part. maybe he put the mistake there on purpose? PS: what you suggested.  doesn't work.  thanks anyway

Comment: @ClankWarrior This is a proper solution. I think your lecturer made a mistake.

Answer (score 2):

If the `store` function doesn't need to change the `filename` content then it should be a `const`. The function prototype is not well and you have to do some workaround. Copy the string to a non-const array and pass it instead, or just use a non-const string.

```
char filename[] = "array.dat";
```

Comment: thanks bro, but like Mr Sahu, that didn't answer the actual question.  My question is, the answer given.. is it Definitely wrong?  thanks.

Comment: @ClankWarrior: We don't know, it seems to be a wrong function declaration while it doesn't change the `filename`. Everything depends on the content of `store`. I prefer to make `filename[]` a `const` in the `store`.